# How do I load images from URLs into tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently running this:

```
image = urllib.urlopen(imgUrl)
pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{'incept/DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
```

and I get this error:

> Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.

Comment: Can you post a full runable code, What is the meaning of the `gfile`?

Comment: sorry, I want to place the img data into a [bytesio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o),  but i didn't find any api can be used in tensorflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was quite simple... All I had to do was call the `read` method on response from urlopen. The following works like a charm:

```
image = urllib.urlopen(imgUrl)
pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{'incept/DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image.read()})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a method to load it into NumPy and then load that into TensorFlow. This is likely more reliable, more flexible.

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/02/convert-url-to-image-with-python-and-opencv/